# Error when making POST request to server from angular 5

Tags: html, angular, rest, post

When I make a POST request to the server it returns this error:

ERROR 
Object { headers: {…}, status: 400, statusText: "OK", url: "serverURL", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for serverURL: 400 OK", error: null }

I am successfully making the DELETE request to the same URL and I can access the data with my browser. The POST request looks like this:

```
    private postrequest() {
            const httpOptions = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Content-Type':  'application/json',
            })
        };
            let body = {
       firstname:this.myarray[0],
       host:(this.myarray[1]+':'+this.myarray[2])
       }

       return this.http.post(this.serverURL, body, httpOptions ).subscribe(res => console.log(res));
   }
```

The successful DELETE request looks like this:

```
private deleterequest() {
        for (var i = this.delArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if ((this.delArray[i]) !== undefined) {
                const httpOptions = {
                headers: new HttpHeaders({
                    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
                })
            };
                this.http.delete(this.serverURL  + this.delArray[i], httpOptions).subscribe(res => console.log(res));

            }
        }
        this.getPeers();
    }
```

Comment: Why are you putting a Content-Type header on a DELETE request?

Comment: HTTP 400 just means the server says it is a bad request. It doesn't say what is bad about the request. You need to do more debugging.

Comment: (The server seems pretty broken since it is saying `400 OK` instead of `400 Bad Request` or `200 OK`.)

Comment: You are creating the headers but not sending them

Comment: the `options` variable is unused in both code samples.

Comment: The server seems fine because I can make the POST with curl and it works fine (obvs the 400 OK is not good but it works otherwise) it also loads when I hit the address with my browser. Could it be a syntax problem?

Comment: @Quentin wrt. the 400/OK thing, I think it's a Chrome client-side bug. As an example if you send an invalid username/password combo to IdentityServer4's /connect/token handler it responds with 400 Bad Request, which you can confirm in Fiddler. Firefox's console correctly shows `{ status: 400; statusText: "Bad Request" }` but Chrome shows `{ status: 400; statusText: "OK"}`. The mind boggles.

Answer (score 0):

you are forgetting to add in the options

```
private postrequest() {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json','Accept': 'q=0.8;application/json;q=0.9'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
    let search = new URLSearchParams();
    this.http.post(this.serverURL, {firstname:this.myarray[0], host:(this.myarray[1]+':'+this.myarray[2])}, options).subscribe(res => console.log(res));
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately. I have sorted it out and I shall edit the question.